# Treeviewitem focus prevents contextmenu from showing

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently trying to set the focus on the selected value of my treeview and then display a contextmenu built in the code behind.

Both the focus and the display of the contextmenu work fine individually, but when i have both in the same block, only the focus fires and the contextmenu does not show?

I would like to find out why my treeviewitem focus is blocking the context menu from showing.

here is my onclick event

```
private void TextBlock_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //searches up the tree until it finds the first treeviewitem and sets the focus to it.
        TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

        if (treeViewItem != null)
        {
            treeViewItem.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        tvProjects.Tag = treeViewItem.Header;




        var fm = new FileMenu();
        var m = new MainViewModel();

        //Create new contextmenu and set datacontext and itemsource
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        cm.DataContext = m;
        cm.ItemsSource = m.MenuItems;

        //set bindings through style
        Style style = new Style();
        style.TargetType = typeof(MenuItem);
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MenuItem.HeaderProperty, new Binding("Header")));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MenuItem.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Items")));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MenuItem.CommandProperty, new Binding("Command")));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("CommandParameter")));
        cm.ItemContainerStyle = style;

        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;

        //Show the menu
        tb.ContextMenu = cm;
        tb.ContextMenu.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it was not handling both events, the line

```
e.Handled = true;
```

prevented the rest of the code from beeing executed, because the MouseButtonEventArgs has been handeled already so the code won't bother executing the rest.

After removing the above line of code, everything worked as it should.